# Python 3 Radio button controlling label text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button, label

I am in the process of learning Python3 and more of a necessity, the TkInter GUI side. I was working my way through a book by James Kelly, when I encountered this problem. All his examples made a new window with just label/canvas/check box etc which seemed to work OK.

But as I wanted to experiment in a more real world scenario I put most things on one window. This where I encountered my problem. I can not get the radio button in the frame to alter the wording of a label in the parent window.

Complete code is:-

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *

def win_pos(WL,WH,xo=0,yo=0) :

# Screen size & position procedure
# Screen size
    SW = home.winfo_screenwidth()
    SH = home.winfo_screenheight()
# 1/2 screen size
    sw=SW/2
    sh=SH/2
# 1/2 window size
    wl=WL/2
    wh=WH/2
# Window position
    WPx=sw-wl+xo
    WPy=sh-wh+yo
# Resulting string
    screen_geometry=str(WL) + "x" + str(WH) + "+" + str(int(WPx)) + "+" \     + str(int(WPy))
    return screen_geometry

# Create a window 
home=Tk()
home.title("Radio buttons test")
# Set the main window
home.geometry(win_pos(600,150))

lab1=Label(home)

lab1.grid(row=1,column=1)

fraym1=LabelFrame(home, bd=5, bg="red",relief=SUNKEN, text="Label frame text")

fraym1.grid(row=2,column=2)

laybl1=Label(fraym1, text="This is laybl1")

laybl1.grid(row=0, column=3)

var1=IntVar()

R1=Radiobutton(fraym1, text="Apple", variable=var1, value=1)
R1.grid(row=1, column=1)

R2=Radiobutton(fraym1, text="Asus", variable=var1, value=2)
R2.grid(row=1, column=2)

R3=Radiobutton(fraym1, text="HP", variable=var1, value=3)
R3.grid(row=1, column=3)

R4=Radiobutton(fraym1, text="Lenovo", variable=var1, value=4)
R4.grid(row=1, column=4)

R5=Radiobutton(fraym1, text="Toshiba", variable=var1, value=5)
R5.grid(row=1, column=5)

# Create function used later
def sel(var) :

    selection="Manufacturer: "

    if var.get() > 0 : 

        selection=selection + str(var.get())

    lab1.config(text=selection)

R1.config(command=sel(var1))
R2.config(command=sel(var1))
R3.config(command=sel(var1))
R4.config(command=sel(var1))
R5.config(command=sel(var1))

R1.select()

mainloop()
```

I realise that there is room for improvement using classes/functions but I need to get this resolved in my head before I move on. As it can be hopefully seen, I'm not a complete novice to programming, but this is doing my head in.

Can a solution, and reasoning behind the solution, be given?

Comment: Please try to [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your label's text by assigning the same variable class object, `var1` as its `textvariable` option as well but since `lab1`'s text is slightly different, try removing:

```
R1.config(command=sel(var1))
R2.config(command=sel(var1))
R3.config(command=sel(var1))
R4.config(command=sel(var1))
R5.config(command=sel(var1))

R1.select()
```

and modify `sel` to:

```
def sel(*args) :

    selection="Manufacturer: "

    selection=selection + str(var1.get())

    lab1.config(text=selection)
```

and then call `var1.trace("w", sel)` somewhere before `mainloop` as in:

```
...
var1.trace("w", sel)
mainloop()
```

---

Also for a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

manufacturers = ["man1", "man2", "man3", "man4", "man5"]

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Please select a manufacturer.")
lbl.pack()

# create an empty dictionary to fill with Radiobutton widgets
man_select = dict()
# create a variable class to be manipulated by radiobuttons
man_var = tk.StringVar(value="type_default_value_here_if_wanted")

# fill radiobutton dictionary with keys from manufacturers list with Radiobutton
# values assigned to corresponding manufacturer name
for man in manufacturers:
    man_select[man] = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=man, variable=man_var, value=man)
    #display
    man_select[man].pack()


def lbl_update(*args):
    selection="Manufacturer: "
    selection=selection + man_var.get()

    lbl['text'] = selection

#run lbl_update function every time man_var's value changes
man_var.trace('w', lbl_update)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Example with label's *identical* to that of radiobutton's value:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# radiobutton group will the button selected with the value=1
num = tk.IntVar(value=1)

lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=num)

zero = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Zero", variable=num, value=0)
one = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="One", variable=num, value=1)

#display
lbl.pack()
zero.pack()
one.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Nae for your input, but your suggestions resulted in:- TypeError: sel() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @John_S I'm sorry you're right. You need to change `def sel():` to `def sel(*args):` as `trace` sends some internal arguments to the function as well. I updated my answer for correction.

Comment: Thanks Nae, it's now all working as it should. Just got learn about trace, and what (*args) means. John